# How to use a logical argument to choose where to open R shiny app (RStudio viewer pane or browser)

Tags: r, shiny

I'm developing an R shiny app that is wrapped in a function. Let's call it launchApp(). I want to add the Browser argument to launchApp() so that when Browser = FALSE the app is launched in RStudio, whereas when Browser = TRUE the app is launched in the browser.

Setting Browser = TRUE works as expected, but Browser = FALSE causes the app to be launched without also opening the usual RStudio viewer. I can't figure out how to fix this issue.

Here's a reprex, with a fake app launched by the function launchApp(Browser = FALSE). I would expect it to correctly open the app in the RStudio Viewer when Browser = FALSE, but that doesn't happen.

```
library(shiny)

# Define a function to launch the Shiny app
launchApp <- function(Browser = FALSE) {
  # UI
  ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Minimal Shiny App"),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        sliderInput("slider", "Number of bins:",
                    min = 1, max = 50, value = 30)
      ),
      mainPanel(
        plotOutput("distPlot")
      )
    )
  )
  
  # server
  server <- function(input, output) {
    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
      x    <- faithful$waiting
      bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$slider + 1)
      hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
    })
  }
  
  # Launch the app with the specified browser option
  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server, options = list(launch.browser = Browser))
}

# This seems to launch the app, but I do not see the RStudio viewer pop-up
launchApp()
# I only get a console message: Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3889
# if open that link in the browser, I see the app and I can interact with it


# This one launches the app in the browser correctly
# launchApp(TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting `launch.browser = FALSE` is intended to be used in non-interactive sessions.

I don't see the point of wrapping your app in a function to launch it.
Please see `?runApp`:

> launch.browser: If true, the system's default web browser will be
> launched automatically after the app is started. Defaults to true in
> interactive sessions only. The value of this parameter can also be a
> function to call with the application's URL.

and check the following:

```
library(shiny)

# UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Minimal Shiny App"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("slider", "Number of bins:",
                  min = 1, max = 50, value = 30)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot")
    )
  )
)

# server
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    x    <- faithful$waiting
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$slider + 1)
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
  })
}

# Launch the app with the specified browser option
appObj <- shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

# opens default browser
# runApp(appObj, launch.browser = TRUE)

# opens app in viewer pane
runApp(appObj, launch.browser = function(url) {invisible(.Call("rs_shinyviewer", url, getwd(), "pane", NULL, PACKAGE = "(embedding)"))})
```

PS: if you still wish to write a custom function just copy and paste the the above anonymous function and pass it to the `launch.browser` parameter.

Comment: That's not what I needed, I guess I didn't explain myself well enough.

Anyways, I've built an [app package](https://f-neri.github.io/FAST.R/) using the suggestion from [Mastering Shiny](https://mastering-shiny.org/scaling-packaging.html#converting-an-existing-app), which says to wrap the app in a function call. That's why I wrapped in the app in a function. There might be better ways of doing it, but I'm a beginner with R and shiny so I don't really know any.

Comment: @fneri it might not be what you needed but it is what you asked for. Your answer is using `launch.browser` without setting it. So it can be the default or something else (depending on the users configuration).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a very simple workaround - I honestly don't know why that wasn't the first thing I tried.

```
library(shiny)

# Define a function to launch the Shiny app
launchApp <- function(Browser = FALSE) {
  # UI
  ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Minimal Shiny App"),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        sliderInput("slider", "Number of bins:",
                    min = 1, max = 50, value = 30)
      ),
      mainPanel(
        plotOutput("distPlot")
      )
    )
  )
  
  # server
  server <- function(input, output) {
    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
      x    <- faithful$waiting
      bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$slider + 1)
      hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
    })
  }
  
  # Launch the app with the specified browser option
  # simple ifelse wrap prevents from calling launch.browser = FALSE when Browser = FALSE 
  if (Browser == FALSE) {
    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
  } else {
    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server, options = list(launch.browser = TRUE))
  }
  
}

launchApp() # and launchApp(TRUE) correctly launches into the browser
```